# Blog component doesn't work properly when change the name of page in AEM 6.0

Tags: blogs, aem

I'm working on blog component of AEM 6.0. the problem is when i change the name of parent page i.e blog from blog to blog1 then other components of blogs like pages, authors,archiving stop working . No data comes in these components and if i change the name from blog1 to blog they again work properly. Is there any hardcoding is done for blog name ? if yes can you please specify if i want to change the name of blog how can i resolve it ?

[image]

Comment: Hey, i had a doubt that how you guy's are using blog component, using overlay or extending the component, can you share the steps for it, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and raise discussion on Adobe Forum

http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__hmrl-hi_gents_i_faced.html

My investigations shows that to generate authors,archiving,tags AEM6 uses Lucene search through **/var/search-collections/ugc-blog-search** that is not updating properly on changing content.

If you are using only components from the box try to modify you content via pageManager e.g. copy

```
pageManager.copy(pageManager.getPage('/content/geometrixx/en/blog'), '/content/geometrixx/en/blog_pm' , 'blog_pm', false, true);
```

That may help. In case you are working with custom components based on SCF API it is still unpredictable behavior.